# Reading/Writing a named pipe in Java?

Tags: java, io, named-pipes, fifo

How do I read and write to a FIFO pipe using Java? Also, is the reading method blocking? I need to read a pipe and I need the program to wait until there's something in the pipe.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check [Not able to read from named pipe in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246862/not-able-to-read-from-named-pipe-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're trying to *create* the named pipe in Java, which you can't, it's just another file. Open it with a `RandomAccessFile` in `"rw"` mode and just read and write.

Comment: Is it better to use RandomAccessFile instead of FileOutputStream?

Comment: Not if you only need to write to it, but the normal pattern is that you both read and write.