# Is it possible to open a named pipe with command line in windows?

Tags: windows, named-pipes

I want to interact with the pipe manually , but so far I can only do this in the programe,which is not very intuitive.

The effect I want to achieve is a little similar to :

```
telnet localhost 3306

tail -f file.txt
```

Anyone get my idea?

Answer (score 5):

Look here: [http://support.microsoft.com/kb/68941](https://web.archive.org/web/20120709091125/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/68941)

> There are two utilities shipped with SQL Server designed to help test
> network named pipes. The MakePipe.exe and ReadPipe.exe utilities are
> installed during installation of both the client and server components

Comment: The link to Microsoft Knowledgebase is dead.

Comment: @Johannes Use the [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20150109055409/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/68941).

Answer (score 5):

From PowerShell

```
PS>$pipe = New-Object System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream("DummyPipe", "InOut")

PS>Get-ChildItem -Path "\\.\pipe\" -Filter *DummyPipe*
```

More explanation:
https://decoder.cloud/2019/03/06/windows-named-pipes-impersonation/

Answer (score 1):

There is a free command line utility to create and write/read from named pipes on Windows: https://github.com/psmay/windows-named-pipe-utils

Answer (score 0):

cygwin may have named pipes you can use.  See also [How to open a Windows named pipe from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634564/how-to-open-a-windows-named-pipe-from-java)

Answer (score 0):

no there is no command line interface for windows named pipes see
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe for more info