# Named Pipes with Command Prompt

Tags: c++, batch-file, named-pipes

Is it possible to pipe to a named pipe using the command prompt

```
dir >"\\.\pipe\my_named_pipe"
```

my_named_pipe being a pipe created by a win32 application

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
HANDLE pipe= CreateNamedPipe("\\\\.\\pipe\\my_named_pipe",PIPE_ACCESS_INBOUND,PIPE_TYPE_BYTE,1,500,500,NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT,NULL);

char* buf = new char[501];
ReadFile(pipe,buf,500,NULL);
std::cout << buf << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This seems like something that's open to fairly trivial testing.

Comment: And if it's not possible, it would be fairly easy to write a small utility that takes `stdin` and sends it to a named pipe.

Comment: Note `>` is not piping, is redirection! `|` is what should be used.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to open a named pipe with command line in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670039/is-it-possible-to-open-a-named-pipe-with-command-line-in-windows)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried on windows XP

```
dir >\\.\pipe\my_named_pipe
```

and it worked properly.

Comment: Looks like this does not work in windows 10? I tried to type `dir > \\.\pipe\my_named_pipe` and the result is `The system cannot find the path specified.`

Answer (score -1):

According to Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe the answer is no for Windows and yes for Unix. But Windows can run Unix so it depends if you want to run Unix Services. See for more info http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Services_for_UNIX