# Logging GC information in the application

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, logging

Is there a way to forward the garbage collection information (for example the output of `-XX:+PrintGCDetails` or `-verbose:gc`) to a logger within the Java application (sl4j + logback in my case)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those messages are generated by the JVM native process and not from Java code, so you just can

1. Redirect output to file using `-Xloggc` (no rotation)

   - [How to redirect verbose garbage collection output to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161647/how-to-redirect-verbose-garbage-collection-output-to-a-file)
2. Pipe stdout directly (several rotation options)

   - [Log rotation of stdout?](https://superuser.com/questions/291368/log-rotation-of-stdout)
   - [Rolling garbage collector logs in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822097/rolling-garbage-collector-logs-in-java)
   - [Garbage collector log (loggc) file rotation with logrotate does not work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353401/garbage-collector-log-loggc-file-rotation-with-logrotate-does-not-work-properl)

Answer (score 3):

An interesting approach would be to redirect gc.log to a named pipe
`-Xloggc:/my/named/pipe`
[How to write GC log to named pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24395623/how-to-write-gc-log-to-named-pipe)

then read that pipe form the application itself:
[How to open a Windows named pipe from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634564/how-to-open-a-windows-named-pipe-from-java)

and log to an arbitrary (e.g. async rolling) logback logger from the code.

Tried that on a Windows machine. Unfortunately, it is trickier to setup on Windows than on Linux.

On Windows it works basically with help of an additional [Powershell script](https://github.com/sshcherbakov/gc-logger/blob/master/GCLogPipeServer.ps1) (can be a dedicated application as well).
This [sample project](https://github.com/sshcherbakov/gc-logger) also contains a demo application that can be used right away to test the GC logs redirection to Logback via SLF4J.