# How to write GC log to named pipe

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I want to configure the gc log so that it can write to a named pipe?

Does anyone know whether it is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A named pipe is a type of file and you can write to it like any other file.

Try

```
-Xloggc:/my/named/pipe
```

Note: you want to make sure the pipe is being read or it could cause the JVM to stop.