# GC log rotation support in Open JDK 1.6.0_22

Tags: java, rotation, garbage-collection

I want to config Garbage Collector log rotation:

```
-XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=2 -XX:GCLogFileSize=512.
```

will it work for java 6 version 22?
I need to know when this fix included in java 6 (from which version) and if it will work in my version (java 6 update 22).

Answer (score 1):

Based on this Blog post : [Rolling Java GC Logs](http://jyates.github.io/2012/11/05/rolling-java-gc-logs.html), the GC logs can be automatically rotated as of **Oracle Java 1.6_34** (**or 1.7_2** in the latest minor version).

It looks like you are out of luck for Java 6_u22. You will probably need to rotate your GC logs by yourself using a cron job.

In order to implement **manual rotation of GC logs**, see [Garbage collector log (loggc) file rotation with logrotate does not work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8353401/772000).

Comment: can you explain how can I rotate the GC log manually? I do not restart the program every day, so I can`t give a different path to the GC log in each start/shutdown of the server. How can I save all the GC log data so it will not erase the information above it`s limited size?

Comment: You can either just update your JVM to run with the automatic GC rotation, or look at this Q/A about manual file rotation : http://stackoverflow.com/q/8353401/772000

Comment: I need the time stamp (not relative). can I do something like this: java -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -verbose:gc >> gc.log?  or  java -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -Xloggc:logs/gc.log >> gc.log instead of verbose:gc?

Comment: you can use both, all the GC logs from teh verbose:gc will go to the logs/gc.log file