# sonarqube A variable substitution for JVM arguments

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

Trying to add the following option under sonar.properties

```
sonar.web.javaOpts=-Xmx1g -Xms1g -XX:MaxPermSize=160m -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true \
 -Xloggc:"/data/sonarqube/logs/gc-$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H%M).log" -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:-UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 \
 -XX:GCLogFileSize=10M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/data/sonarqube/logs
```

But sonarqube fails to start with following message

> Error: Could not find or load main class +%Y-%m-%d_%H%M).log

Not sure how to make the evaluation happen can anybody help ?

Thanks
ravi

Answer (score 0):

Script variable substitution `$(date...)` is not supported as this property is not read/executed by shell.

Anyway I don't think this is the correct way to rotate GC logs as the filename would be resolved only once when starting application. `-Xloggc:/data/sonarqube/logs/gc.log` is enough. Rotation index is automatically appended to filename (`gc.log.0` for instance). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12277309/229031 and http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6941923 for more details.

Comment: That is correct but once gc.log.0 gets created it keeps getting overwritten when instance is restarted. Any suggestion on how to make it write to gc.log.1 ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I don't have any proposal in mind.