# Garbage collection logs rotation

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm

will the parameter `%t` also perform log rotation for collecting GC logs?

```
-Xloggc:/data/logs/gc-%t.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You should enable logging by unlocking `-XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation`

See also [Rolling garbage collector logs in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822097/rolling-garbage-collector-logs-in-java)