# How do I make connection between csharp and Java

Tags: c#, java, pascal, named-pipes

Csharp App1 have implemented named pipes communication. It requires several parameters to start. I have functional pascal App2 class which connects with App1 with following method:

```
//declaration of client event 
myClient: TClient;
//connects to App1
myClient:= TClient.Create(self,"App1path","user|pass|url");
//runs application which had been connected before
myClient.Run("App1Param");
```

Do you know any way to connect like this with Java?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that

```
myClient:= TClient.Create(self,"App1path","user|pass|url");
```

should be

```
klient:= TClient.Create(self,"App1path","user|pass|url");
```

right?

Comment: Is there somewhere a description of TClient?

Answer (score 0):

In my knowledge Java supports named pipes (you can use [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) to open them) but I've never used them.
Apparently, it depends whether you're on windows or on linux.
Maybe you could go for a socket, instead.

This question is about communication between java and c# (not delphi, but still better than nothing) with named pipes:
[Concurrent read/write of named pipe in Java (on windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974989/concurrent-read-write-of-named-pipe-in-java-on-windows)

EDIT

There's another possibility: redirecting standard input and standard output. Never done in java, but probably it's feasible.

Answer (score -1):

Code integration is becoming a legacy now. You should opt for web services architecture while working with different technologies. It creates seamless communication and well maintained code. There are plenty of web services frameworks available these days and you can chose one depending your level of comfort on a particular coding language.