# An efficient way to use Windows Named Pipe for IPC

Tags: java, ffmpeg, ipc, named-pipes

I am using `jna` module to connect two processes that both perform FFMPEG commands. Send `SDTOUT` of FFMPEG command on the server side to NampedPipe and receive `STDIN` from that NampedPipe for other FFMPEG command on the Client side.

this is how I capture `STDOUT` and send into the pipe in server Side:

```java
InputStream out = inputProcess.getInputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[maxBufferSize];
while (inputProcess.isAlive()) {
     int no = out.available();
     if (no > 0 && no > maxBufferSize) {
        int n = out.read(buffer, 0,maxBufferSize);
        IntByReference lpNumberOfBytesWritten = new IntByReference(maxBufferSize);
        Kernel32.INSTANCE.WriteFile(pipe, buffer, buffer.length, lpNumberOfBytesWritten, null);
     }
}
```

And this is how I capture `STDIN` and feed it to the Client Side:

```java
OutputStream in = outputProcess.getOutputStream();
while (pipeOpenValue >= 1 && outputProcess.isAlive() && ServerIdState) {
      // read from pipe
      resp = Kernel32.INSTANCE.ReadFile(handle, readBuffer,readBuffer.length, lpNumberOfBytesRead, null);
      // Write to StdIn inputProcess
      if (outputProcess != null) {
          in.write(readBuffer);
          in.flush();
      }
      // check pipe status
      Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetNamedPipeHandleState(handle, null,PipeOpenStatus, null, null, null, 2048);
      pipeOpenValue = PipeOpenStatus.getValue();
      WinDef.ULONGByReference ServerId = new WinDef.ULONGByReference();
      ServerIdState = Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetNamedPipeServerProcessId(handle, ServerId);
}
```

But I faced two problems:

1. High CPU usage due to iterating two loops in Server and Client. (find by profiling resources by  VisualVM)
2. Slower operation than just connecting two FFMPEG command with regular `|` in command prompt. Speed depends on buffer size but large buffer size blocks operation and small buffer size reduce speed further.

Questions:

1. Is there any way not to send and receive in chunks of bytes? Just stream `STDOUT` to the Namedpipe and capture it in Client. (Eliminate two Loops)
2. If I cant use NampedPipe, is there any other way to Connect two FFMPEG process that runs in different java modules but in the same machine?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're constantly polling process states stdin on server side without waiting for any events or sleeping the thread.
Probably you want to take a look here:
[Concurrent read/write of named pipe in Java (on windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974989/concurrent-read-write-of-named-pipe-in-java-on-windows)

Cheers!

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Thank you. Your advice solved my problem